# Excluding fwmark(ed) Packets from Wireguard Tunnel

Tags: iptables, routing, wireguard

In the scenario described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/917411/), I ended up with this config in the client (the endpoint WG server has two public IPs)

```
[Interface]
Address = <ip_to_use>/32
PrivateKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[Peer]
PublicKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <wg_server_ip>:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 10
```

Now I would like to exclude from the Wireguard tunnel either all processes from an user **or** all packets (to and from) certain ports.

It has been brought to my attention that this can be done using the fwmark set by WG itself, and I don't need to use another mark, as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/920888/34560).

This is IPtables 1.6 on Ubuntu 16.04. **How can I exclude from the WG tunnel, using the mark created by wg-quick, either per user or per port?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04.1, which enabled the following new feature to handle the problem in one line:

```
PostUp = ip rule add uidrange 0-0 lookup main
PostDown = ip rule del uidrange 0-0 lookup main
```

Running 16.04.5 with kernel 4.15 didn't allow for `uidrange`. Using uidrange also requires iproute2 to be of a higher version than provided by the Xenial repo. Iptables 1.6.1 alone is not enough.